# SQL Create table from multiple tables & columns

Tags: sql, join, multiple-columns, ms-access-2013, multiple-tables

I'm trying to create a table "USAGEFACT" with multiple columns from 4 tables.
I am using MS access 2013.
The error I get is just simply "Syntax error in CREATE TABLE"

The tables I am using are

FACT  (Semester_ID, Class_ID)  .
Class  (Class_ID, Class_Description)  .
Semester  (Semester_ID, Semester_Description)  .
Student  (Student_ID, Class_ID)  .

*These aren't the only columns in these tables

At the moment I have the following Query which is incorrect :

```
create table USAGEFACT as 
(select c.CLASS_DESCRIPTION, s.SEMESTER_DESCRIPTION, st.TYPE, st.SEX 
from FACT, CLASS as c, SEMESTER as s, STUDENT as st 
where FACT.CLASS_ID = c.CLASS_ID 
and s.SEMESTER_ID = FACT.SEMESTER_ID 
and c.CLASS_ID = st.CLASS_ID);
```

I fear that I need to use a join. I thought maybe if I could create a set of 2 temporary tables, each containing 2 tables which were joined, then joining these 2 temp tables which were each created from 2 other tables.

Deeply appreciated.

Comment: Why is it incorrect? What RDBMS are you using. Please add a tag.

Comment: In access you must use SELECT INTO stametent.

Comment: But it *is* join, although harder to read. Is question about creating table and populating it with select statement (while having select that outputs exactly what you need), or you having problems with select itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MS Access you can't use `CREATE TABLE as SELECT` but `SELECT ... INTO` statement

So, I've used explicit `JOIN` notation for further readable of your query

Try this:

```
SELECT c.CLASS_DESCRIPTION as CLASS_DESCRIPTION,
s.SEMESTER_DESCRIPTION as SEMESTER_DESCRIPTION,
st.[TYPE] as ST_TYPE, st.SEX as SEX
INTO USAGEFACT
FROM FACT
INNER JOIN CLASS as c
    ON FACT.CLASS_ID = c.CLASS_ID 
INNER JOIN SEMESTER as s
    ON s.SEMESTER_ID = FACT.SEMESTER_ID 
INNER JOIN STUDENT as st 
    ON c.CLASS_ID = st.CLASS_ID
```

Comment: With the INTO statement, will this create the table if no such table exists or do you need to create the table with no columns then use the INTO statement to add these columns?

Comment: select into is the same command of create table as select. With this statement you create a table (USAGEFACT) with columns c.CLASS_DESCRIPTION, s.SEMESTER_DESCRIPTION, st.TYPE, st.SEX

Comment: Thank you Joe. Your solution has a "Syntax error in FROM clause". May it be because the table "FACT" is never used in terms of its columns but merely called in a JOIN?

Comment: I just get the pop-up saying "Syntax error in FROM clause". The first "JOIN" is highlighted when "ok" is clicked on the pop-up.

Comment: I've changed st.TYPE as TYPE in st.TYPE as ST_TYPE (because TYPE is a reserved word)

Comment: I've added INNER before JOIN. Try again and tell me

Comment: "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'FACT.CLASS_ID = c.CLASS_ID INNER JOIN SEMESTER as s ON s.SEMESTER_ID = FACT.SEMESTER_ID INNER JOIN STUDENT as st ON c.CLASS_ID = st.CLASS_ID"

Comment: Can you try with only JOIN and if it's OK we extend to two join operations and so on (change the list fields in according your join)?

Comment: You are speaking with someone very new to SQL, I'm not sure what you mean